# For the purposes of DFT, is "the" primitive root of unity $w_n = e^{ 2\pi i / n }$ or $w_n = e^{-2\pi i / n }$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm working on the section of Strang's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 4e that discusses discrete Fourier transforms. To make the exercises easier, I wrote myself a Python script that generates the $n$th Fourier matrix as described here:

[image: Strang's definition of the nth Fourier matrix]

I've run into trouble regarding the definition of $w$. While any integer value of $k$ in $e^{ 2\pi k i / n }$ will get us *a* complex root of unity, to fill in the matrix, we need the *primitive* complex root of unity.

Strang defines $w_n$ as $e^{ 2\pi i / n }$:

[image: Strang's definition of w with positive exponent]

But when I coded $w_n$ as such in my DFT matrix function, it kept giving me the complex conjugate of what I wanted, and [someone on Stack Overflow pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57619979/custom-dft-function-returns-the-complex-conjugate-of-what-it-should) that I need to use $w_n = e^{-2\pi i / n }$ instead.

This is consistent with the definition given on Wikipedia:

[image: Definition with negative exponent from wiki DFT page]

But here's what throws me off. Looking at the unit circle, it seems like the primitive root of unity should be the one corresponding to a $2\pi / n$ rotation in the counterclockwise direction. That's what Strang does in this example diagram for $w_8$:

[image: Strang's unit circle, positive exponent omitting i]

(The omission of $i$ is just a typo, right?)

If we replace that circled bit with $e^{-2\pi i / 8 }$, we get $\bar{w}$, an angle in the fourth quadrant, and taking increasing powers of it will move us around the unit circle in a *clockwise* direction. If that's correct,

- Why does the Fourier matrix reverse the usual convention of counterclockwise rotation?
- Why does my textbook seem to state one definition and use another?
- In general, when should I use $w_n = e^{ 2\pi i / n }$, and when should I use $w_n = e^{ -2\pi i / n }$?

As always, thank you.

---

Thank you all for your detailed explanations. Indeed, Strang's convention is to work with the inverse of what's described elsewhere, hence the change in sign.

However, this introduces a new issue in one of the assignment problems. Question 3.5.3 asks,

> If you form a 3 by 3 submatrix of the 6 by 6 matrix $F_6$, keeping only the entries in its first, third, and fifth rows and columns, what is that submatrix?

The answer text reads simply,

> The submatrix is $F_3$.

But using my Python function with $w_n = e^{2\pi i / n }$, I get the following inconsistent result:

```
F6 matrix:
[[ 1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5+0.866j -0.5+0.866j -1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j  0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j  1. -0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -1. +0.j     1. -0.j    -1. +0.j     1. -0.j    -1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j  1. -0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j     0.5-0.866j -0.5-0.866j -1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j  0.5+0.866j]]

F6 submatrix:
[[ 1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j]]

F3 matrix (should match the above)
[[ 1. +0.j     1. +0.j     1. +0.j   ]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5+0.866j -0.5-0.866j]
 [ 1. +0.j    -0.5-0.866j -0.5+0.866j]]
```

You can see the code [here](https://tio.run/##ZY7NboMwEITP@ClG6iE2Qm0VqhyQeuUlKAc7OMVVWVu2KeHpqQNJf5Tbzrc7s@Pm2FsqFzM46yNoHNwMGUCuQDiaTQS3dPqEepCRk6gYyx5AsYe3NsKeMJKJM8smvCbfoz47vv9AfpmdwRNIrA5lqIOJAc5O2gcYihYSKdSbM8vqzb1J3qCZ8pzLXAmcrE93huAlvevUoF2R@ocEy7yOoydep3dMbmnejtTxtfhBFKVg6o6XK3c@1eG7@nDtU@1uTP4s3yitw6juLprmudgXL23bVMVt/Osqr6HgobfjZ3eRxx6x15DKfmnxm6XEsnwD).

Comment: By the way, the typo $e^{2\pi/8}$ that you circled has been corrected in the 5th edition of Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra.

Comment: Strang has many linear algebra books, so it's probably best to use the full title. I think you're referring to Linear Algebra and its Applications.

Answer (score 4):

There is one linguistic problem. It seems you are asking about "the" primitive root of unity. However, a primitive $n$th root of unity is just a complex number with $z^n = 1$ and $z^m \neq 1$ for $1 \leq m \leq n-1.$ In particular, there are Euler phi $\phi(n)$ such primitive roots.

Comment: This is exactly my question, hence the scare quotes. In order to create a DFT matrix, we need to choose a single value for $w$, but there are many available.

Answer (score 2):

The 5th edition of Strang's Introduction to Linear Algebra contains the following note (section 9.3, p. 447):

> *Important note.* Many authors prefer to work with $\omega = e^{-2\pi i /N}$, which is the *complex conjugate* of our $w$. (They often use
>   the Greek omega, and I will do that to keep the two options separate.)
>   With this choice, their DFT matrix contains powers of $\omega$ not
>   $w$. It is $\bar F$, the conjugate of our $F$. $\bar F$ goes from
>   physical space to frequency space.
>
> $\bar F$ is a completely reasonable choice! MATLAB uses $\omega = e^{-2\pi i/N}$. The DFT matrix `fft(eye(N))` contains powers of this
>   number $\omega = \bar w$. **The Fourier matrix $F$ with $w$'s
>   reconstructs $y$ from $c$. The matrix $\bar F$ with $\omega$'s
>   computes Fourier coefficients as `fft(y)`.**

It would be a mistake to assume that, in Strang's notation, the discrete Fourier transform of $x$ is $Fx$. Strang does not make this claim. If we define $F$ as Strang does, using $w = e^{2\pi i/N}$, then the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the discrete Fourier basis is $F^{-1} = (1/N)F^*$. So
$$
\text{DFT}(x) = F^{-1} x = (1/N) F^* x.
$$
(If we normalize the discrete Fourier basis, then we don't need the factor of $1/N$.)

Comment: Does $F^*$ mean "the complex conjugate of $F$"? This is new notation to me.

Comment: $F^*$ denotes the conjugate transpose of $F$.

Comment: So, which is "the nth Fourier matrix": $F$, or $F^*$?

Comment: @Max The only person I've heard use the term "Fourier matrix" is Strang, so I'd say that the $n$th "Fourier matrix" is what Strang calls $F$. (I think it's his term.) The different term "DFT matrix", I think, is supposed to satisfy $\text{DFT}(x) = (\text{DFT matrix})x$. So, the DFT matrix is $(1/N) F^*$. (If we normalize the discrete Fourier basis, we would not need the factor of $1/N$.)

Comment: Even if the terminology is not completely standardized, the important thing to understand is that the columns of $F$ are the discrete Fourier basis vectors, and that $F^{-1}$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the discrete Fourier basis. And the DFT simply changes basis from the standard basis to the discrete Fourier basis. So $\text{DFT}(x) = F^{-1} x$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying these conventions quoting from Strang's book (I wish I could find a used 5e here in Korea...). After straightening this issue out, though, it *still* seems like $F$ is used inconsistently in the assignment problems. I've made an edit to my post; perhaps you could take a look if you get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that what Strang computes the matrix $F$ for is what is usually considered the **inverse DFT**, the reconstruction of the values from the Fourier coefficients, 
$$
y_k=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}c_m(z_k)^m=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}c_me^{i2\pi\frac{mk}n}
$$
where the Fourier coefficients occur as polynomial coefficients.

The usually-considered-as-**forwards DFT**  computes the coefficients from the values,
$$
\hat y_m=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y_ke^{-i2\pi\frac{mk}n}.
$$
One easily finds $\hat y_m=nc_m$. This is what other sources present as the primary transform, so that mistaken associations may occur.